# Windows server manager got uninstalled after deactivating windows power shell ISE (Windows server 2016)

Tags: windows-server-2016, powershell-5.0, powershell-ise

After removing Windows Powershell ISE feature, the server manager became unavailable until reenabling/activating Powershell ISE. any help on how to remove it without affecting server manager

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm, you disabled PowerShell ISE, and left PowerShell 5.1 enabled?

Comment: Yes, i did. only ISE is disabled